# how to draw the implementation stereotype in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

How to draw an "implementation stereotype" in UML class diagram? What is the notation for the "implementation stereotype"?

Comment: a google search brought up [this](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html#stereotype). Looks like you draw a box and label it with «stereotype».

Comment: Almost. The label would be `<<implementation>>`. That's it.

Comment: Try and give more details on your quest so that we can give a more roboust answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the notation '< < stereotype > >' goes before the name of the stereotype. Hence, for your case I believe it will look like this '< < stereotype > > Implementation'

Check out this link for more details.http://www.uml-diagrams.org/stereotype.html